# How to highlight row that is found after typing in search field in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using datatable 1.10.4 and what i want is whenever I search for a record in search input field it should highlight the record found. I tried following but it gives error that "body.unhighlight is not a function"

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#table_search').DataTable({
        //***************REMOVE PAGINATION-SET TO TRUE IF PAGINATION IS REQUIRED**********************//
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSort": false
    });

    table.on('draw', function () {
        var body = $(table.table().body());

        body.unhighlight();
        body.highlight(table.search());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have this error, because you forgot to include some libraries in your code.

1. [//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js](http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js)
2. [//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.css](http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.css)
3. [//bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.js](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.js)